# Let $f(x)= \sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^n \sin\frac{1}{3^n x} $ For all $x>0$ for which the series converge. Prove that $f$ is defined and differentiable.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $f(x)= \sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^n \sin\frac{1}{3^n x} $ For all $x>0$ for which the series converge. Prove that $f$ is defined and differentiable.

For the series to converge, I'm assuming the only positive values of $x$ are when $\frac{1}{3^n x} = n\pi$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ or $x=\frac{1}{3^n{n\pi}}$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$. However, as Dr. MV points out below, this is clearly wrong, as he proves in his answer the series is well defined for all $x>0$

Taking the derivative of $f$ with respect to $x$ we obtain:

$$f'(x)=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {2^n}{3^n x^2} \cos\frac{1}{3^n x} $$

Applying one more time Ratio Test to the terms of $f'$ We conclude convergence of the derivative series.

Comment: How can $x$ depend on a "dummy" index of summation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Direct application of the ratio test reveals

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2^{n+1} \sin(3^{-(n+1)}x^{-1})}{2^n \sin(3^{-n}x^{-1})}=\frac23$$

So the series converges for all $0<x$.

Now, for a fixed interval ($0<a\le x \le b$), one can easily show that the derived series converges uniformly for $x \in [a,b]$.

Thus, term by term differentiation is permissible for $a\le x\le b$ for all $a>0$ and $b$.

Can you do the rest?

---

Alternative Approach

For each $x$, there is a number $N$ so that when $n\ge N$, $\sin (3^{-n}x^{-1})>0$.  Can you find $N$?

So, for $n>N$, the series is one of positive coefficients $a_n=2^n \sin(3^{-n}x^{-1})>0$.

Note that $\sin x<x$ for all $x>0$.

Thus, for $n>N$, $0 < a_n <2^n3^{-n}x^{-1}=(\frac23)^n x^{-1}$.

Comment: One straightforward way to proceed is to use that fact that for small $x$, $\sin x \approx x$.  To make the argument rigorous, just use "Big-O" notation for the remainder of the series.

Comment: Ah... Oh...! I got it Dr. MV, it finally clicked... I like the alternative approach better. I proved that sin x < x for all x > 0 using MVT. Then 2^n sin(3^−n x^−1) is clearly less than 2^n (3^−n x^−1), using ratio test this series converges, and therefore f(x) converges as well... using term by term differentiation, and again ratio test, f'(x) clearly converges as well. Thank you so much.

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.